# How to overwrite @media stylesheet

Tags: css

I'm working on a child theme in wordpress. I want to leave the original stylesheet unattached, I just want to cancel all this:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {}
@media (max-width: 650px) {}
@media (max-width: 450px) {}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the !important tag to overwrite other CSS definitions.

`max-width: 0px !important;`

Comment: But I want to overwrite all together, what's inside @media (max-width: 800px) {} as it never was.